# How to use ConvLSTM2D with VGG16

Tags: keras, lstm, video-processing, vgg-net

I am trying to use convlstm2D along with VGG16 using the code below:

```
video = Input(shape=(no_of_frames, img_width, img_height, channels))
cnn_base = VGG16(input_shape=(img_width, img_height, channels), weights="imagenet", 
include_top=False)
cnn_base.trainable = False
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn_base)(video)
encoded_sequence = ConvLSTM2D(64, kernel_size=(7, 7), strides=(2, 2),padding='same', 
return_sequences=True)(encoded_frames)
hidden_layer_1 = Dense(activation="relu", units=512)(encoded_sequence)
hidden_layer_2 = Dense(activation="relu", units=20)(hidden_layer_1)
outputs = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(hidden_layer_2)
model = Model([video], outputs)
```

Running the code gives me the following error msg:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/vislab/PycharmProjects/Firefront/ConvLstm_Classification.py",
>   line 75, in 
>       callbacks=[checkpoint, early])   File "/home/vislab/anaconda3/envs/Firefront/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/vislab/anaconda3/envs/Firefront/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 1418, in fit_generator
>       initial_epoch=initial_epoch)   File "/home/vislab/anaconda3/envs/Firefront/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py",
>   line 217, in fit_generator
>       class_weight=class_weight)   File "/home/vislab/anaconda3/envs/Firefront/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 1211, in train_on_batch
>       class_weight=class_weight)   File "/home/vislab/anaconda3/envs/Firefront/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 789, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='target')   File "/home/vislab/anaconda3/envs/Firefront/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py",
>   line 128, in standardize_input_data
>       'with shape ' + str(data_shape)) ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_5 to have 3 dimensions, but got
>   array with shape (20, 2)
>
> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Can anyone advice me on how to proceed forward.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `return_sequences=False`. You are not classifying each frame, you're classifying the whole video.

Then you also need either a `Flatten` (only for fixed image sizes) or a global pooling before the `Dense` layers, to eliminate the extra dimensions.

Comment: Changing it gives me the same error:
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 2)

Comment: You need a `Flatten` or a  global pooling.